# Iran’s Mahan airline defies sanctions in shadowy aircraft deal

Tags: articles

I have just seen an article in FT with the title

> Iran’s Mahan airline defies sanctions in shadowy aircraft deal

It seems to me that an article is missing in this sentence. Namely, it should be "in **a** shadowy deal". Is this correct? If yes, why the article is missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that the article a is missing.  This is because newspaper headlines are often written in [Headlinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).  Dropping articles to save space is very common in Headlinese.